# MySQL combine two table fields by matching their id

Tags: php, mysql, sql

For example I have created two tables.

**Table One: t5zgu_property_message**

```
msg_from msg_to subject message

57       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx
57       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx
57       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx
42       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx
```

**Table Two: t5zgu_users**

```
id username

42 Jack
57 Rocky
```

I want output like this way:

```
msg_from msg_to subject message msg_from  msg_to

57       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx  Rocky     Jack
57       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx  Rocky     Jack
57       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx  Rocky     Jack
42       42     xxxxx   xxxxxx  Jack      Jack
```

My current query is:

```
SELECT 
    t5zgu_property_message.id,
        t5zgu_property_message.msg_from,
        t5zgu_property_message.msg_to,
        t5zgu_property_message.subject,
        t5zgu_property_message.message,
        t5zgu_users.username as msg_from
FROM 
    t5zgu_property_message,
        t5zgu_users
WHERE
    t5zgu_property_message.msg_from = t5zgu_users.id

ORDER BY t5zgu_property_message.id DESC
```

This query is working perfect with **msg_from** and getting right output but I don't know how to write for **msg_to**.

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Suggestion: you don't really have a date for your messages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All you need is to join the `users` table again:

```
SELECT 
    t5zgu_property_message.id,
        t5zgu_property_message.msg_from,
        t5zgu_property_message.msg_to,
        t5zgu_property_message.subject,
        t5zgu_property_message.message,
        t5zgu_users.username as msg_from,
        t5zgu_users2.username as msg_to
FROM 
    t5zgu_property_message,
    t5zgu_users,
    t5zgu_users t5zgu_users2
WHERE
    t5zgu_property_message.msg_from = t5zgu_users.id
    AND
    t5zgu_property_message.msg_to = t5zgu_users2.id

ORDER BY t5zgu_property_message.id DESC
```

Or the same thing using `JOIN` syntax:

```
SELECT 
    t5zgu_property_message.id,
        t5zgu_property_message.msg_from,
        t5zgu_property_message.msg_to,
        t5zgu_property_message.subject,
        t5zgu_property_message.message,
        t5zgu_users.username as msg_from,
        t5zgu_users2.username as msg_to
FROM 
    t5zgu_property_message
    JOIN t5zgu_users ON t5zgu_property_message.msg_from = t5zgu_users.id
    JOIN t5zgu_users t5zgu_users2 ON t5zgu_property_message.msg_to = t5zgu_users2.id
ORDER BY t5zgu_property_message.id DESC
```

Comment: Hey I am getting error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 't5zgu_users2.username as msg_to FROM t5zgu_property_message JOIN t5zgu_' at line 8

Comment: @Rajnikanth Oops, there was a missing comma - fixed now. You should be able to spot and fix this yourself, you know

Answer (score 0):

Try the following statement:

```
SELECT 
        p.id,
        p.msg_from,
        p.msg_to,
        p.subject,
        p.message,
        u1.username as msg_from
        u2.username as msg_to
FROM 
    t5zgu_property_message p LEFT JOIN 
        t5zgu_users u1 ON u1.id = p.msg_from
    LEFT JOIN t5zgu_users u2 ON u2.id = p.msg_to

ORDER BY p.id DESC
```